# How can I create a user and set the password so I can ftp to my Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a Micro instance and downloaded a key for access to this. However I have a wordpress blog and that is asking for a username and passsword so it can use ftp to upload some plugins.

How can I create a new user for the ec2 instance? Currently I just have ec2-user. Do I need to create this when setting up the server or can I do this after the initial set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When WordPress asks for an FTP username/password, that means the permissions on your webroot are too restrictive for WordPress to update itself, or to add new plugins, etc. I actually LIKE that, since to have the permissions more permissive means the site and server are a bit more vulnerable to uploads/injections, etc.

So to install your new plugin I would recommend you do one of two things:

1. One option is that you could SSH into your server instance, identify the directory of your webroot (often the webroot is in`/var/www/html/`) and then `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html && chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/html`). That will make your permissions wide-open and you can perform any updates or installations on your site using the WordPress dashboard. You will not be asked for an FTP username/password while these permissions are open. The problem is, you'll then want to go back and reset your permissions afterward to something more restrictive. For a good primer on that, see [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/08/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/) from Smashing Magazine, or the official Codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).
2. The second method is a bit more indirect, a good bit more complicated, but safer. It involves using a source control system like Git on both the WordPress server and your own local workstation. If you create a private repository in something like GitHub, and load your site's code into that repository, that means you could also create a clone of it on your workstation, add the plugin(s) or new theme(s) there, and then commit and push the code back to GitHub. You would then hop into your server, cd to the webroot, and then `git pull` to retrieve your changes with no permission changes needed.

There are many reasons I favor the latter solution, but I know there is more setup involved. So if that feels like too much, you should learn how to do the first method comfortably. It would actually be a great chance to write a simple bash script that can OPEN up your permissions, and then another script to CLOSE them back down, automatically for you. (You can find [just such a script](https://gist.github.com/macbleser/9136424) here from a GitHub user.)